# What are the differences in drilldowns and drillthrough reports?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

In SSRS, what are the differences in drilldowns and drillthrough reports? Only developers experienced working on both kind of reports can answer this. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Drill DOWN means a way to filter the results to a more 
detailed level from the Parent Level.Like plus and minus symbols.For example initially you will see summary level data if you want to go in detail you need to click on plus symbol

Drill Through on the other hand means to drill into (get 
into ) another report for getting more details. The values 
from the Parent(Main) report are passed to the Child 
(Detailed Report) for filter condition.It just navigation between two different reports

These report are used by everyone.Its simple reports but need some practice

Comment: Great, can you please provide some reference where there are examples implemented with both drill downs and drill throughs?